# How to call function in async

Tags: function, asynchronous, npm

function `a()` in async function :

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db(mongourl);
    function a (){
      //do something
    }
});
```

how to trigger `a()` in another async function?

```
server.on('clientConnected', function(client) {
    //do a()
});
```

Comment: Why do you declare the function within a .connect call? You have to declare function a in an accessible scope!

Comment: Make `a()` a global function.

Comment: @DavidIbl thanks david, ok, so the mongo client doesnt need to open all of time? and we could take it to on clientconnected function?

Answer (score 0):

Make `a()` a global function:

```
function a() {
    // body 
}
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db(mongourl);
    a()
});

server.on('clientConnected', function(client) {
    a()
});
```